# Chaining Option and Result with `?` operator

Tags: rust

Is there a way to chain a `Result` and an `Option` with `?` so that the following code works? What would be the return type? I am happy to return some kind of an Error if the option is `None`.

```
struct Status {
   serial: Option<&'static str>;
}

fn serial(status_mutex: Mutex<Option<Status>>) -> Result<&'static str, ...> {
    status_mutex.lock()?.serial?
}
```

Comment: Note that, unless you are writing a very specific application, you want to `unwrap()` on a failed `Mutex::lock()`. This is because locking a `Mutex` can fail only if some other thread paniced while holding the lock, and you probably want to handle that by panicking in the current thread as well. In that light, the return type could be `Option<&'static str>`, and the implementation `status_mutex.lock().unwrap().serial`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Option::ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or) or [`Option::ok_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or_else):

```rust
fn serial(status_mutex: Mutex<Option<Status>>) -> Result<&'static str, ...> {
    status_mutex.lock()?.serial.ok_or(your_error_here)
}
```

Edit: as @user4815162342 commented, `your_error` returned by the `serial` fn and the one you would use in `ok_or` should implement `From<PoisonError>`.

Another approach would be to [map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) the `lock` error:

```rust
fn serial(status_mutex: Mutex<Option<Status>>) -> Result<&'static str, your_error> {
    status_mutex.lock()
        .map_err(conver_to_my_error)?
        .serial
        .ok_or(your_error_here)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Rust book, [section 3.3.1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html), this specific use case is mentioned. In short, using the `?` operator like the question is suggesting isn't currently allowed in Rust, but here's the relevant paragraph from the section:

> One current restriction is that you cannot use `?` for both in the same function, as the return type needs to match the type you use `?` on. In the future, this restriction will be lifted.

Edit:

On the nightly version of Rust, you could implement a custom Error that implements `From<NoneError>`. This would allow for using the `?` operator to unwrap a value of type `Option<T>`. If that unwrap returns a `None` variant, then an error can be returned. Check the documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/option/struct.NoneError.html).